VB6 install fails on Win 10 (21H2)
There are lots of tutorials and magic spells explaining how to install VB6 on Win 10, and I believe I've read and followed all of the advice(s), with no joy. I've done this on another Win 10 (Pro) box with no issues.
This installation fails at the last step ("updating your system") and smells like a failure to write to the registry. [Do I need to change some registry permissions or access rights, and if so, how is that done?]
I am an admin and the install is run 'as admin'
Edited to add: Checking the registry permissions shows that admins (and my user) have full access to the keys in question.
At the point of failure, the install has copied all its files, and none of the expected registry entries have been made. Any ideas why this should be?

Lots of head scratching later, the issue is (mostly) resolved. There had been a previous installation on another drive, and all the needed registry entries still pointed to that folder.
I spent a few minutes deleting any keys that pointed to that previous folder and re-ran the install, and it took.
One issue remains, which I'll ask in another Q
